# MS SQL Index value updates

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, indexing, sql-insert

**Setup:**
SQL Server 2008 R2

**Back Story:**
We have a proc that is called in several threads at once. These threaded proc calls will sometimes write overlapping (duplicate) data to the table they write to. In the insert statement I have a "NOT EXISTS" clause to make sure duplicates are not inserted, but we are still getting duplicates.

**Question:**
The "NOT EXISTS" clause does a simple select, is it possibly, since the inserts for the threaded calls are only milliseconds apart, that some of the indexes (specifically the ones used by the "NOT EXISTS" clause) are not updated yet? Therefore it doesn't see the existing record before doing the insert?

**Thoughts:**
This could be me not understanding how SQL does its thing as well. If I have an insert with a "WHERE NOT EXISTS", does it check to make sure none of the records exist before doing the insert? Or does it check in a row-by-row manner as it inserts each row? If it's the former (checking all before doing any insert) then I suppose it is possible that one of the other calls has not yet completed it's insert.

I am stumped.

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
INSERT INTO [SomeTable] (Col1,Col2)
SELECT
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB
FROM
    #TempTable
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [SomeTable]
        WHERE Col1 = #TempTable.ColumnA
              AND Col2 = #TempTable.ColumnB
    )
```

Comment: Could you show us the code?  Guessing takes too long.  See [Writing The Perfect Question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Comment: Are you using transactions in your code?

Comment: No transactions, and the proc is 10,000 lines long. :) It is a straight forward insert though, it is inserting records from a temp table into a user table, where the entry does not already exist. If you run the proc for an employee, then run it again directly after, it doesn't insert anything, as it see the records are already there.`test`

Comment: Code example added. Yes it is that simple in the production code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to lock the table for the duration of the transaction. Other threads will wait until the transaction finishes (commit or rollback).

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ

BEGIN TRANSACTION

--do stuff

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Comment: As the OP is checking for existence he needs to also be able to lock a non-existent row. `REPEATABLE READ` does not provide that.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server uses the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level by default. That means that during a select the read lock on each row is only held while the select is actively accessing that row.

That means that after the `SELECT` is done and before the `INSERT` happens, another thread could insert the row, even if that gap is only a few nano seconds long.

Even a `MERGE` statement does not prevent concurrent inserts as there is some time between the search part and the insert part. (See http://sqlity.net/en/1645/merge-wonders-insert-or-use/ for more details.)

You need a lock to be held on a non existing row for the entire transaction that includes the check and the following insert. The only way to make that happen is to use a wrapping transaction and set the transaction isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE`.

Something like:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
BEGIN TRAN
  IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT ...))
  BEGIN
   INSERT....
  END;
COMMIT;
```

---

UPDATE:

Because you provided an example now trying to do the two steps together, let me re-post my example from the referenced article with all the stuff removed that is not important for this case:

```
MERGE dbo.Product WITH(HOLDLOCK) AS p
USING (VALUES(@ProductName, @ProductNumber))n(Name,ProductNumber)
ON p.ProductNumber = n.ProductNumber
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(Name, ProductNumber)
VALUES(n.Name, n.ProductNumber)
```

The `HOLDLOCK` hint has (locally) the same effect as setting the transaction isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE`. Because `MERGE` is a data altering statement, it is automatically executed within a transaction.

Using the `MERGE` statement has the added advantage that you can easily add the `UPDATE` branch if the need arises later on.